# Count how many times user click back button (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I need to count how many times user click back button from current page. Is it possible?

Comment: why do you want to do this? There may be a better way of achieving the same result.

Comment: I need to avoid user pressing button too many times

Comment: why? what are you trying to prevent or stop?

Answer (score 1):

There is an event for BackButtonPress

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
```

Comment: eh, then whats the problem? Try putting a counter inside just as SENTHIL has given below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this.

```
int counter =0;

protected override void OnBackKeyPress
                  (System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    counter++;

    textbox1.text = counter.tostring();

    navigation process;
}
```